# EXCEL LINKS CHANGING MACRO

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have created a Macro which opens an Excel file and changes its existing external links to new ones. At the end of this process, everything is fine with the links, however, I can see that the Macro somehow changes the formatting of certain cells in certain Workbooks (e.g. from Custom formatting to Accounting). Since the Excel file I am working with has a lot of different Workbooks and cells, I really need the formatting to stay static, as I am printing the Sheets as reports, and they shouldn't look odd.

Here is my code - you can clearly see it doesn't even scratch formatting of cells. Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Thank you!

```
Sub ChangeLinksMacroINPUT()

Dim Mesec As String
Mesec = Range("E7").Value

Dim MesecEC As String
MesecEC = Range("F7").Value

Dim Godina As String
Godina = Range("E6").Value

Dim GodinaC As String
GodinaC = Range("F6").Value

Dim PrethodnaGodina As String
PrethodnaGodina = Range("E4").Value

Dim PrethodenMesec As String
PrethodenMesec = Range("E5").Value

Dim PredPrethodenMesec As String
PredPrethodenMesec = Range("E8").Value

Dim OsnovnaPateka As String
OsnovnaPateka = "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\"

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim VariableWB As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina & "\INPUT" & Godina & Mesec & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0
Set VariableWB = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets("PAR").Select
Range("D3").Value = MesecEC
Range("D5").Value = GodinaC

'*****INPUT Minus edna godina*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & PrethodnaGodina & "\INPUT_" & PrethodnaGodina & "\INPUT" & PrethodnaGodina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & PrethodnaGodina & "\INPUT_" & PrethodnaGodina & "\INPUT" & PrethodnaGodina & Mesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****INPUT Minus eden mesec*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina & "\INPUT" & Godina & PredPrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina & "\INPUT" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****INV MOVEMENT*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INV_" & Godina & "\Inv_mvmt_" & PrethodenMesec & "_20" & Godina & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INV_" & Godina & "\Inv_mvmt_" & Mesec & "_20" & Godina & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
'
'*****KWH*****
VariableWB.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\KWH_" & Godina & "\KWh_" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xls", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\KWH_" & Godina & "\KWh_" & Godina & Mesec & ".xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****Maintenance*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MNT_" & Godina & "\Maintenance_" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xls", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MNT_" & Godina & "\Maintenance_" & Godina & Mesec & ".xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****MIS*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MIS_" & Godina & "\MIS" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MIS_" & Godina & "\MIS" & Godina & Mesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****MIS MINUS EDNA GODINA*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & PrethodnaGodina & "\MIS_" & PrethodnaGodina & "\MIS" & PrethodnaGodina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & PrethodnaGodina & "\MIS_" & PrethodnaGodina & "\MIS" & PrethodnaGodina & Mesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****MR*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MR_" & Godina & "\MR" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xls", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MR_" & Godina & "\MR" & Godina & Mesec & ".xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****PDATA*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\TECH_" & Godina & "\PData_" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & "_v.xls", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\TECH_" & Godina & "\PData_" & Godina & Mesec & "_v.xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****SALES*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\SALES_" & Godina & "\SALES" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xls", NewName:= _
        "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\SALES_" & Godina & "\SALES" & Godina & Mesec & ".xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'*****RM Stocks*****
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\TECH_" & Godina & "\RM_STOCKS_" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & "_v.xls", NewName:= _
         "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\TECH_" & Godina & "\RM_STOCKS_" & Godina & Mesec & "_v.xls", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'VariableWB.Save
'VariableWB.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect it's a bug. Is the number format for the Normal cell style changing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using `On Error Resume Next`? as @Rory said, it is most probably masking an error

Comment: @Zac I actually meant that it's a bug in Excel. It happens from time to time.

Comment: @Rory: Yup, I've seen similar things happen when working with Excel but my first thought would be to remove the `On Error Resume Next` to ensure that there is nothing in the code that's causing the problem. If that's not the case, I would then go down the route of maybe forcing the cell format

Comment: Do the links have dollar signs ($)? Perhaps Excel is auto formatting as accounting due to that?

Comment: Did you already tried debugging your code step by step? Ctrl + F8

Comment: as a last step copy the formatting from the source and apply to the destination, or conversely set all the formatting the way you want it through your coding?

Comment: I removed the "On Error Resume Next" completely. When I run the code, it does not show any errors, and the problem with the formatting is gone. Thanks a lot to everyone who replied.